# Blender 3.2.2 doesn't use my Intel iRIS Xe Graphics on my laptop

Tags: gpu

In Blender 3.2.2, blender is using my CPU for rendering which is and i5 Processor. but I also have a Intel Xe graphics card, but blender isn't using it for some reason. By rendering with the CPU, its slowing my rendering times by a lot. Is there any kind of way/feature that can force Blender to use my Xe Graphics card?

I have tried searching up this problem, but there is no video or article that was helpful.

The other "duplicate" question to enable GPU rendering doesn't include the answers on how to enable GPU rendering on Intel iRIS Xe Graphics in Blender 3.2.2, there is only a section for Intel Arc GPU.

Comment: If it is not listed as supported, then it cannot be used for GPU rendering. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: The other duplicate question have answers. The first one which starts with "ensure GPU support" and sends you to the [manual to check the current supported hardware](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). You would have noticed there that only Intel Arc  is supported.

Comment: Intel XE are integrated GPUs, not dedicated GPUs. They can render only via the OpenCL API, which [Blender dropped sinces version 3.0](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#OpenCL). What you can try is to use the latest [2.93 LTS](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-93/). But otherwise, you need to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: (Clarification: what I meant by "Intel XE are integrated GPUs, not dedicated GPUs" is that you probably won't get a huge perf boost in the first place, not that they use OpenCL because of being integrated, that's not a thing)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to setup your preferences in order to tell Blender what to use with your hardware :
go to Edit -> Preferences and go to the System tab

You'll be able to select both your CPU and GPU card + the algorithm Blender can use with your card
[image: system preferences]

Then, you need to tell Blender which render engine to use, and what to do with your current scene.
You can co to the Properties panel and go to the render properties to select what you need

[image: Cycles render properties]